# React Perf render count

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to improve the performance of React app. I'm using [React Perf](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html) and I see that some component has wasted render count of 29 but when I add `console.log` to the `render` method I don't see it get written 29 times to the console.

What does it means when 29 render count is listed in `printWasted` of React Perf?

Comment: Instances refer to how many times render() is being called, but 29 seems quite excessive. What version are you using?

Comment: In instances column I have 1, in render count I have 29

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, `printWasted` tells you the time wasted to on components which didn't render anything. According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html#printwasted) -

> “Wasted” time is spent on components that didn’t actually render anything, e.g. the render stayed the same, so the DOM wasn’t touched.